# How to calculate the probability with a Gaussian Mixture Model in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This problem is solved. Thank you @dpwe
I first make the GMM by gmdistribution. Then I want to have a function that can return the probability of my Observation. That is:

```
GMMObject = gmdistribution(Vec_Mean, Matrix_Covariance, Vec_Weight);
Probability = posterior(GMMObject, Vec_Observation) * Vec_Weight;
```

The value of `Probability` should equal to p(x) 
[image]
But I find that `log(Probability)` is not equal to `nlogl` where:

```
[Dummy, nlogl] = posterior(GMMObject, Vec_Observation)
```

So I am wondering where is my mistake.

Comment: The first return from posterior() is the posterior values, i.e. the individual w_k N(x|\mu_k, \Sigma_k) terms *normalized by p(x)*, so sum(posterior(...)) = 1.  Your expression for Probability ignores this normalization.  Also, I think the Vec_Weight is probably already factored in to the posterior returns.

Comment: Hi @sflee, I have a very similar problem, did you manage to solve yours?. Here is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257192/classify-using-gmm-with-matlab